# How to make a debian package with a binary AND .so files?

Tags: debian, packaging

I know how to create a simple debian package that includes a single binary. I use "dpkg-deb --build" command.

However, I now need to add

1. multiple binaries AND
2. multiple shared libraries (.so) files

and make a single debian package.

How do I add shared libraries (.so files) to this script so that they get included in the debian package?

For example, here is what I normally do.

```
echo "Making debian..."
mkdir -p test_package/bin
cp /usr/local/bin/test test_package/bin

mkdir -p test_package/DEBIAN
cat > test_package/DEBIAN/control <<-DEBCONTROL
Package: test
Version: 1.0 
Section: stack overflow
Priority: required
Architecture: armhf
Maintainer: whoever
Description: this is a test
DEBCONTROL

mkdir -p test_package/usr/share/doc/test
cat > test_package/usr/share/doc/test/changelog.Debian <<-CHANGELOG
test (1.0) unstable; urgency=low
  * Some change log
CHANGELOG

gzip --best test_package/usr/share/doc/test/changelog.Debian
dpkg-deb --build test_package
```

Comment: You can create a simple package like this, but for anything nontrivial you should probably have a `debian/rules` file and use the regular build toolchain (`debhelper` etc).

Comment: @tripleee Could you provide a concrete example to illustrate how this can be done?

Comment: That's a really broad topic. Probably start at https://wiki.debian.org/Packaging